# Read multiple records as one in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

everyone, I am in the middle of a grouping of rows of a table Relationship with the same name as one.
example- the table will look like

```
Parent_name .... Childern_name
==============
A Mittal ........ Children 1
-----------------
A Mittal ........ Children 2
-----------------
A Mittal ........ Children 3
-----------------
B Mittal .........children 1
-----------------
B Mittal .........children 2
```

Now I created an HTML where I want to see only

```
A Mittal 
B Mittal
```

For which I have to define in views -

```
parentnames= Relationship.objects.distinct(Parent_name)
```

But it's not working kindly help. Is there any other way also to do it?

Comment: Your `Relationship` does not use `ForeignKey`s?

Comment: Hey @WillemVanOnsem Both are in same table so yes no Foreign Key . I just want to a list where name will not be repeated. Rather group all rows with same parent name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a `QuerySet` of `Parent_name`s by using [**`.values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
parentnames= Relationship.objects.values_list(
    'Parent_name', flat=True
).distinct()
```

That being said, by storing the names in the `Relationship`, you introduce *data duplication*. It makes it harder to update a name. For example, if `A Mittal` is renamed to `C Mittal`, it will require some querying to rename all `Parent_name`s and `Child_name`s where `A Mittal` is present. Therefore one often makes a dedicated model to store details about the object (like its name), and uses `ForeignKey`s. This is also more efficient, since by default a `ForeignKey` will add a database index on the corresponding column.

Comment: Is their any way without value too ? where i can fetch the whole row instead of only value

Comment: @ritu: only for *PostgreSQL*, you can use `Relationship.objects.distinct('Parent_name')`.

Comment: mine is on SQL.

Comment: @ritu: no, standard SQL has no syntax for this. For example an `ArrayAggregate` is also not standard SQL.